# Using rayon's parallel iterators for a tree object

Tags: rust, rayon

I have a `Vec<ValidRelationshipTree>` and I would like to use rayon's parallel iteration to process each tree in parallel. I cannot do so as my `ValidRelationshipTree` doesn't satisfy `std::marker::Sized`.

Definition of `ValidRelationshipTree`, whose size is clearly known at compile time:

```rust
// size = 16 (0x10), align = 0x8
struct ValidRelationshipTree {
    root: RefCell<Rc<ValidRelationshipNode>>,
}
```

Compilation error:

```
the method `into_par_iter` exists for struct `Vec<ValidRelationshipTree>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`[metadata::relationships::ValidRelationshipTree]: std::marker::Sized`
which is required by `[metadata::relationships::ValidRelationshipTree]: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
`[metadata::relationships::ValidRelationshipTree]: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
which is required by `[metadata::relationships::ValidRelationshipTree]: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
```

Since my structure's size is known at compile time, I don't understand how `std::marker::Sized` isn't implemented. I've tried to read through this trait's documentation, researching similar rayon issues, but I just don't understand. I even tried creating a wrapper `struct` around my `Vec<ValidRelationshipTree>` but no dice.

If anyone could help fill in my gap of knowledge that would be greatly appreciated <3.

In case it's relevant, here is the definition of `ValidRelationshipNode`:

```rust
struct ValidRelationshipNode {
    payload: String,
    extended: String,                             
    parent: RefCell<Weak<ValidRelationshipNode>>, // Use Weak<T> to avoid reference cycles
    children: RefCell<Vec<Rc<ValidRelationshipNode>>>,
}
```

### Concrete code example

The following sequential block compiles just fine:

```rust
let forest: Vec<ValidRelationshipTree> = self.generate_relationship_trees(n_tables, true);

let mut extended: Vec<String> = forest
    .into_iter()
    .flat_map(|tree: ValidRelationShipTree| {
        tree.nodes_with_length(n_tables)
            .into_iter()
            .map(|node: Rc<ValidRelationshipNode>| node.extended().clone())
    })
    .collect();
```

And a trivial test case that errors:

```rust
let forest: Vec<ValidRelationshipTree> = self.generate_relationship_trees(n_tables, true);

let extended_par: Vec<String> = forest
    .into_par_iter() // ERROR: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
                     // [metadata::relationships::ValidRelationshipTree]: std::marker::Sized`
    .map(|node| node.extended().clone())
    .collect();
```

Comment: You've read the error message wrong. `ValidRelationshipTree` is sized but `[ValidRelationshipTree]` (slice of trees) is not sized. Additionally, it looks like this error is misleading, but I can't tell if that's correct without seeing the code it's referring to.

Comment: Excellent point. I've added a code block that compiles fine with sequential iteration. The error also happens with a trivial iteration so I'm worried that it won't help deduce the problem.

Comment: I can only imagine that it has something to do with the `Rc` and `RefCell` that are internally used that rayon isn't liking. Maybe they don't implement `Send` and I should try an implementation with `Arc`. Thoughts?

Comment: I'd also guess it's `Rc` and `RefCell`.

Comment: Sorry, in the first code block we see that forest is just a `Vec<ValidRelationshipTree>`

Comment: My bad, I missed that.

Comment: For sure, thanks for the input. I'll close this and get to learning about `Arc` and friends!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instead call `into_par_iter` as an associated function on `Vec`, you get a more helpful error:

```rust
Vec::into_par_iter(forest)
```

```rust
error[E0277]: `Rc<ValidRelationshipNode>` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:44:5
   |
44 |     Vec::into_par_iter(forest)
   |     ^^^ `Rc<ValidRelationshipNode>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `Rc<ValidRelationshipNode>`
   = help: the following other types implement trait `rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`:
             Vec<T>
             &'data Vec<T>
             &'data mut Vec<T>
   = note: required for `RefCell<Rc<ValidRelationshipNode>>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it appears within the type `ValidRelationshipTree`
  --> src/lib.rs:5:12
   |
5  | pub struct ValidRelationshipTree {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: required for `Vec<ValidRelationshipTree>` to implement `rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
```

The simplest way to get around this is to use [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) instead of `Rc` and [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) instead of `RefCell`.

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};

struct ValidRelationshipTree {
    root: Mutex<Arc<ValidRelationshipNode>>,
}

struct ValidRelationshipNode {
    payload: String,
    extended: String,
    parent: Mutex<Weak<ValidRelationshipNode>>,
    children: Mutex<Vec<Arc<ValidRelationshipNode>>>,
}
```

Then this code probably works, depending on the other functions involved:

```rust
forest
    .into_par_iter()
    .flat_map(|tree| {
        tree.nodes_with_length(n_tables)
            .into_par_iter()
            .map(|node| node.extended().clone())
    })
    .collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably misleading and the actual problem likely lies in the fact that the `ValidRelationshipTree` and `ValidRelationshipNode` structures are using `Rc` and `RefCell` which are not thread-safe.